# Best compression and decompression algorithm for qrcode

Tags: algorithm, compression, qr-code, text-compression

Scenario: Have to generate **qr code** which contains some customer information. It will be scanned in android phone.

The information have to transfer in following process.

```
----------------------Server side---------|| Image ||------Android-----------------------------

original data-->Encrypt--->> Compress---> ||Qr code|| --> Decompress-->>Decrypt-->original data
```

Everything goes well. But **Text compression** is **not efficient.**

Is any efficient way to do this?

Comment: It's not surprising that compressing "random" data like the output of a good block cipher is not efficient. Maybe compress *before* encryption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having tried it, I would say that **Run-Length Encoding** (RLE) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) would be a nice candidate.
The main idea is that you can replace a run of identical symbols with it's length.
So, if you have the 0 and 1 symbols for the pixels (dunno, if they are called like that on a QRcode), then one line of the qr code which would resemble something like this:
`000000000000111111011111111111111110000000001` would be compressed to this:
`12,6,1,16,9,1`